# ATM Machine in Java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have been trying to figure out what is going wrong with this program I'm writing. Heres the full description of what I'm trying to do:
Use the Account class created in Programming Exer- cise 9.7 to simulate an ATM machine. Create ten accounts in an array with id 0, 1, . . . , 9, and initial balance $100. The system prompts the user to enter an id. If the id is entered incorrectly, ask the user to enter a correct id. Once an id is accepted, the main menu is displayed as shown in the sample run. You can enter a choice 1 for viewing the current balance, 2 for withdrawing money, 3 for depositing money, and 4 for exiting the main menu. Once you exit, the system will prompt for an id again. Thus, once the system starts, it will not stop.

The program now only displays the default $100 after each purchase. I've realized the problem is that my accounts are being recreated each time after a transaction. My question is basically what can I do or where can I rewrite the account creation so I avoid this problem. I'm new to programming so I'm still struggling. Thanks in advanced.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            mainMenuOptions();      
    }
            //main menu option method
    public static void mainMenuOptions(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //enter id
        System.out.println("Enter an id: "); 
        int id = input.nextInt();
        //create accounts
          Account [] accounts = new Account[10];
        //initialize 100 dollars
        for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) { 
            accounts[i] = new Account(i, 100); 
        }
        int index = -1; 
        for(int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
            if(accounts[i].getid() == id) {
            index = i; 
            i = accounts.length;
            }               
        }
        if(id <= 9){
            //main menu
            mainMenu();
            //user enters choice in main menu   
            int enterchoice = input.nextInt();                          
            if(enterchoice == 1){
                System.out.println("The balance is " + accounts[index].getbalance());
                mainMenuOptions();
            }
            else if(enterchoice == 2){
                System.out.println("Enter an amount to withdraw ");
                double amount = input.nextDouble();
                //withdraw method
                accounts[index].withdraw(amount);
                mainMenuOptions();
            }
            else if(enterchoice == 3){
                System.out.println("Enter an amount to deposit ");
                double amount = input.nextDouble();
                //deposit method
                accounts[index].deposit(amount);
                mainMenuOptions();
            }
            else if(enterchoice == 4){
                mainMenuOptions();
            }   
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Please enter a correct id");
            mainMenuOptions();
        }

    }
    //main menu method
    public static void mainMenu(){
        System.out.println("Main menu"+"\n1:check balance"+"\n2:withdraw"
                +"\n3:deposit"+"\n4:exit"+"\nEnter a choice");

    }
    }
        class Account{
            private int id = 0;
            private double balance = 0;
            private double withdraw = 0;
            private double deposit = 0;
            private double amount = 0;

            Account(){
            }

            Account(int id, double balance){
                this.id = id;
                this.balance = balance;
            }

            public int getid(){
                return this.id;

            }
            public void setid(int newid){
                id = newid;
            }
            public double getbalance(){
                return this.balance;
            }
            public void withdraw(double amount){
                balance = balance - amount;
            }

            public void deposit(double amount){
                balance = balance + amount;
            }
        }
```

EDIT: When I go to check balance it will re loop me back to the scanners for id and choice. I'm not sure what the problem is here, can someone try to run my code or give me some insight on what might be the problem. Thanks. The program is supposed to be able to go through any choice of transactions, simulating an ATM machine, the id being a number between 0-9. Here is the new updated code.

```
import java.util.Date;
```

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class test {

    private static Account[] accounts = new Account[10];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        accounts();
        mainMenuOptions();      
}
    //main menu option method
    public static void mainMenuOptions() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int enterchoice = -1;
        int id=-1;
        while (enterchoice != 4) {
          mainMenu();
          System.out.println("Enter an id: ");
          id = input.nextInt();
          //enter id
          System.out.println("Enter choice:  ");
           enterchoice = input.nextInt();

          int index = -1;
          for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
            if (accounts[i].getid() == id) {
              index = i;
              break;
            }
          }
          if (enterchoice == 1) {
            System.out.println("The balance is " + accounts[index].getbalance());       
          } else if (enterchoice == 2) {
            System.out.println("Enter an amount to withdraw ");
            double amount = input.nextDouble();
            //withdraw method
            accounts[index].withdraw(amount);               
          } else if (enterchoice == 3) {
            System.out.println("Enter an amount to deposit ");
            double amount = input.nextDouble();
            //deposit method
            accounts[index].deposit(amount);
          } 
        }
      }

     public static void accounts() {
        //create accounts
        //initialize 100 dollars
        for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
            accounts[i] = new Account(i, 100);
        }
    }
    //main menu method
    public static void mainMenu(){
        System.out.println("Main menu"+"\n1:check balance"+"\n2:withdraw"
                +"\n3:deposit"+"\n4:exit");

    }
    }
        class Account{
            private int id = 0;
            private double balance = 0;
            private double withdraw = 0;
            private double deposit = 0;
            private double amount = 0;

            Account(){
            }

            Account(int id, double balance){
                this.id = id;
                this.balance = balance;
            }

            public int getid(){
                return this.id;

            }
            public void setid(int newid){
                id = newid;
            }
            public double getbalance(){
                return this.balance;
            }
            public void withdraw(double amount){
                balance = balance - amount;
            }

            public void deposit(double amount){
                balance = balance + amount;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you want to do multiple transaction in your program using a loop and to you want to save your Account information so it is not lost when you restart the program?  BTW I suggest you use the formatter in your IDE to make the code more readable.

Comment: Yes, the program has multiple id's (0-9) that represent an account. Once you enter say id 1, you can withdraw/deposit or check our balance as many times as you'd like until you hit its exit command. This all works fine just the balance will always remain at the starting $100 because I am currently recreating these accounts each time in the mainMenuOptions. I know this is the problem I just need help on where to move it or what I can do to keep it from constantly recreating the 10 accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you can do it like this bro:

```
public class test {

private Account [] accounts = new Account[10];

public static void main(String[] args) {

        mainMenuOptions();      
}
        //main menu option method
public static void mainMenuOptions(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    //enter id
    System.out.println("Enter an id: "); 
    int id = input.nextInt();

    //initialize 100 dollars
    for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) { 
        accounts[i] = new Account(i, 100); 
    }
    int index = -1; 
    for(int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
        if(accounts[i].getid() == id) {
        index = i; 
        i = accounts.length;
        }               
    }
```

now the Object lives outside of the method, so when the method closes out it won't destroy the object.  The accounts will persist and you should be able to do what you're looking to do from there.

I had the same problem a while back where I had data getting all hosed up in an arraylist.  I had the Object declared at the class level, and it was existing in every loop of my For statement causing doubled up entries in the list.  I moved it inside the For statement and realized that every time the For statement finished a loop it would destroy the object and reinstantiate it.

Give this a try, I think it should get rid of the problem with the account object being recreated every time you invoke the mainMenuOptions() method.

If you're worried about memory overages in bigger applications you can also do it like the other poster was talking about by creating it in the main like so

```
 public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Account [] accounts = new Account[10];
        mainMenuOptions(accounts);      
}
        //main menu option method
public static void mainMenuOptions(Account accounts){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    //enter id
    System.out.println("Enter an id: "); 
    int id = input.nextInt();

    //initialize 100 dollars
    for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) { 
        accounts[i] = new Account(i, 100); 
    }
    int index = -1; 
    for(int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
        if(accounts[i].getid() == id) {
        index = i; 
        i = accounts.length;
        }               
    }
```

in this version you've created the object to live inside the main method.  here I instantiated the object and passed it as an argument to mainMenuOptions.  This way if you decide that you don't want this to be globally available to all sub methods within main, you can now make it live within the space of the main method only and use it as an argument where necessary.

Both of these solutions will work.  My first suggestion is the quick and dirty since it's a small program.  However, in larger programs you may want to use the second method to prevent the object from being available for use in other methods contained within the class.

Comment: How would i get rid of the errors after implementing this, such as the errors like method mainMenuOptions() not applicable for the arguments (Account[]) in the main method

Answer (score 1):

You are recursively calling mainMenuOptions() each time your "transaction" completes. This function recreate all accounts every time.

You should create the accounts just one time, preferably on a separate function called outside mainMenuOptions(), after the main invocation and before the mainMenuOptions(). To do so, you'll have to make the accounts array a property of your main class (test) or pass it to the mainMenuOptions().

Answer (score 1):

Try to Move your accounts object outside outside of the mainmenuoptions method and declare it under the class.

your object gets destroyed at the end of the method after it's called.

Comment: Making it private? I'm not sure how to just move the account creation since its so tied into everything else in the method.

Comment: Ya just slip it up into the class area and make it private. That'll fix the problem with it resetting.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `mainMenuOptions()` which will make all the accounts initialize back to $100.

I suspect you wish to keep the program running and you are trying to achieve so by calling `mainMenuOptions()` no matter what.

To keep the program running, try to:

- initialize the accounts outside of `mainMenuOptions()`, in a separate method that get's called once.
- Then actually call the main method where you receive an option from the user, and exit only when the user inputs an Exit option - 4

example:

```
mainMenu();
System.out.println("Enter Option: "); 
int option = input.nextInt();
while(option != 4) { // keep looping unless user wants to exit
// process the option [deposit, withdrawal etc]

mainMenu();
System.out.println("Enter Option: "); 
int option = input.nextInt();
}

//at this point the user selected exit and you can terminate or do whatever
```

You can try something like this. The idea is to keep asking the user for an option until he decides to leave. You can adapt to your needs.

edit:

```
    public class test {

      private static Account[] accounts = new Account[10];

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      accounts();
      mainMenuOptions();
    }
    //main menu option method
  public static void mainMenuOptions() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int enterchoice = -1;
    int id=-1;
    while (enterchoice != 4) {
      mainMenu();
      System.out.println("Enter choice: ");
      enterchoice = input.nextInt();
      //enter id
      System.out.println("Enter an id: ");
       id = input.nextInt();

      int index = -1;
      for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
        if (accounts[i].getid() == id) {
          index = i;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (enterchoice == 1) {
        System.out.println("The balance is " + accounts[index].getbalance());
      } else if (enterchoice == 2) {
        System.out.println("Enter an amount to withdraw ");
        double amount = input.nextDouble();
        //withdraw method
        accounts[index].withdraw(amount);
      } else if (enterchoice == 3) {
        System.out.println("Enter an amount to deposit ");
        double amount = input.nextDouble();
        //deposit method
        accounts[index].deposit(amount);
      } 
    }
  }

  public static void accounts() {
    //create accounts
    //initialize 100 dollars
    for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
      accounts[i] = new Account(i, 100);
    }
  }

  //main menu method
  public static void mainMenu() {
    System.out.println("Main menu" + "\n1:check balance" + "\n2:withdraw" + "\n3:deposit" + "\n4:exit" + "\nEnter a choice");

  }
```

Comment: Are you saying to do something like i just did in the edit? I get I have to remove it from the method but I'm not sure what I'd do next

Comment: that's a first step.  but as you have probably realised, as soon as you exit the accounts() method, you lose whatever you had in the accounts variable. You need to move the 'accounts' to a instance variable of the class.

Comment: Im sorry I'm getting all confused now. Can you show me the example or something? I've been trying to get this to work for hours now

Comment: Have a look now. Idea is to move the accounts under the class. You were also using the non existing variable index in the mainMenuOptions method. Your edited program wouldn't even compile.

Comment: I am trying to make it an instance of the class, I still have the "cannot make a static reference to the non-static method" on accounts. Can you explain that to me, I thought I did it but I can't figure out why it won't compile

Comment: For the purpose of just running this, make accounts variable static. Alternatively, and better, declare accounts as a local variable of the main method and pass it as a parameter to both accounts() and mainMenuOptions(). Finally have a read about static and non-static methods/variables.

Comment: When I did change it to static It would constantly re loop the enter choice and enter id scans. I can't get into the actual options in the output.

Comment: enterchoice and id were being declared all the time. Check the edit. Also, this will loop until you enter choice 4.

Comment: It turns out it was only the option 1, check balance that was giving me an issue, everything else ran fine. Sorry about that, I don't know why I didn't run the other options as well. Would you be able to explain why overtime i check the balance it just reloops me to enter id and enter choice? It looks fine to me

Comment: Are you sure you are using the code above? I just tried it and it works for every option. For option 1 it should print the balance first and then loop.

Answer (score 1):

ok, so I finally got annoyed enough to load your code and look at it.  Now this looks like a homework assignment so I'm not going to post the solution because you're going to be a shitty coder if you don't know how to solve these things yourself. So I'm going to give you a huge hint.

look at your commented line under where you created the accounts.  You made a For loop down there.

```
//initialize 100 dollars
    for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) { 
        accounts[i] = new Account(i, 100); 
    }
```

I want to ask you something, if I call mainMenuOptions and run this segment of code, what happens when I reach this loop the next time I run this method?

think about that, You'll quickly realize why you're having problems. You'll still have to place the account object outside of mainMenuOptions to prevent the accounts from being destroyed, but you're also going to have to do something with that initialization loop.

Run your code after moving the accounts outside to the class level, and try playing with 2 of the accounts by making a deposit, switching accounts, make a deposit, switch back to the first account and make a balance inquiry.

insert a break point at that initialize account balance portion of your code if you're still having trouble. I'm pretty positive you'll slap yourself in the forehead and yell "wtf was I thinking?"

I got faith in you man.  You got this.  hit me back if you need another hint.

On a side note, make sure you make the accounts object static too when you place it under class.  Can't have a static reference a dynamic object.  The IDE will bark at you. EX:

```
    public class test {

private static Account [] accounts = new Account[10];

public static void main(String[] args) {

        mainMenuOptions();      
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The philosophy for an application that you can exchange money is below:

1. Define final variables like

```
    private final int EURO200 = 200;
    private final int EURO50 = 50;
    private final int EURO20 = 20;
    private final int EURO10 = 10;
    private final int EURO5 = 5;
```

2. Get the amount from the user and divide it with final variables from bigger to smaller with the condition a/b where a>=b.

If the user needs an amount of 210 euro then you get :

```
210/200 = 1 //(rest 10) One 200 euro bill
10/10 = 1   //(rest 0)  One 10 euro bill
```

DONE.

It is simple.